# How to create a mock of the SQS client instead of mocking client functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I am trying to write a unit test for a service I have. The service looks like this:

```
class SQSHealthCheckStrategy {
    constructor(private client: AWS.SQS) {}

    private alias = "foo";

    async check(): Promise<boolean> {
        try {
            const params = {
                QueueName: process.env.AWS_QUEUE_URL,
            };
            const response = await this.client.getQueueUrl(params).promise();
            return (response.$response.error) ? false : true;
        } catch(err) { //do something}
    } 
}
```

So in my test, I need to construct an object of type SQSHealthCheckStrategy and I need to pass in a mocked version of the SQS client. I have tried doing a manual mock by adding a `aws-sdk.js` file at the root level `__mocks__` folder that simply does  `module.exports = jest.genMockFromModule("aws-sdk");`.

Have also tried to use `aws-sdk-mocks` but can't figure out how to create a mock version of the SQS client instead of just testing a mock version of one of the SQS client's functions.